# what's the meaning of two parenthesis in R language

Tags: r

when I am learning the `ggthemes` package in R,Here's [a link](https://github.com/jrnold/ggthemes)!.I see code as follow:

```
p + geom_rangeframe() +
    theme_tufte() +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = extended_range_breaks()(mtcars$wt))
```

so I confuse what's the meaning of `extended_range_breaks()(mtcars$wt)`

`extended_range_breaks` is a function in `ggthemes` package.

function name follows a `()`,why there is the second `()` with parameter `mtcars$wt` in it?how the function `extended_range_breaks` accepts the parameter?

in a normal case,I can only understand usage like this:

```
extended_range_breaks(mtcars$wt)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess what it means is that `extended_range_breaks()` returns another function. Here is a simplified example of returning function in R:

```
myFun <- function() { function(x) x }
myFun()
function(x) x
<environment: 0x10fad05b8>

myFun()(1)
[1] 1
```

You see that `myFun()` returns another function and you can call the function further by passing the parameter as `myFun()(1)`.

Comment: Another example of this that comes to mind is `colorRampPalette`, which returns a function interpolating between colors. For example, `colorRampPalette(c("red","blue"))(10)` returns 10 colors interpolated between red and blue. You could save the function, e.g., `mycol = colorRampPalette(c("red","blue"))` and then do `mycol(10)`, `mycol(3)`, etc., but the first version works as a one-off.

Comment: perfect!thank you very much.I have read the source code of extended_range_breaks and write code testing it.it return a function just as you say.